# Mapping array inside another array using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, spread

I'm testing spread operator inside array to map another array values. Unfortunately, I have come up with weird behavior or I did it wrong. When I return 2 objects using map inside the array, it's only returning the last object. Code below:

```
const cats = ["Tom", "Ginger", "Angela"];

const array = [
  // {
  //   name: "Ben",
  //   sex: "male"
  // },
  ...cats.map((element, index, array) => {
    return (
      {
        name: element,
        sex: element !== "Angela" ? "male" : "female"
      },
      {
        age: element !== "Angela" ? "20" : "18",
        color:
          element === "Tom"
            ? "black"
            : element === "Ginger"
            ? "orange"
            : "white"
      }
    );
  })
];

console.log(array);
```

In console:

```
[{"age":"20","color":"black"},
{"age":"20","color":"orange"},
{"age":"18","color":"white"}]
```

What I expected:

```
[{"name": "Tom", "sex": "male"},
{"age":"20","color":"black"},
{"name": "Ginger", "sex": "male"},
{"age":"20","color":"orange"},
{"name": "Angela", "sex": "female"},
{"age":"18","color":"white"}]
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-thunder-me6mdd?file=/src/index.js) here. Is it available to implement it what I expected? Or there are other alternatives?

Comment: return makes no sense, you are returning two objects with a coma operator. It will not return both objects, that is not how that operator works.

Comment: Also the order looks strange. Why do you expect the first `age-color` object to come after `Tom` but then `Ginger` and `Angela` following each other.

Comment: Oops, I confused the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning two objects with a comma. Comma operator will just return the last item. You need to return an array and use flatMap

```js
const cats = ["Tom", "Ginger", "Angela"];
const result = cats.flatMap(x => ([{
  foo: x
}, {
  bar: x
}]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem essentially was that you did `return({},{})` instead of `return [{},{}]`.

`(a,b)` is called a comma expression, and it evaluates the first expression `a` and then ignores the result, and then only returns the evaluation of the second expression `b`.

```js
const cats = ["Tom", "Ginger", "Angela"];

const array = cats.map((element) => [{
    name: element,
    sex: element !== "Angela" ? "male" : "female"
  },
  {
    age: element !== "Angela" ? "20" : "18",
    color:
      element === "Tom"
        ? "black"
        : element === "Ginger"
        ? "orange"
        : "white"
  }]
);

console.log(array);
```